# How to sort date and time in mfc?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++

I know how to get the current date and time in mfc.but I want to sort the array with the help of date and time datatype.

How can I do this?

Regards,

karthik

Comment: which date/time class you are using?

Comment: ctime and also coledatetime class ...both class are preferable

Comment: `C` or `C++` (or something else)? I believe the answer is different to the different languages.

Comment: As the OP wants `C++`, I've removed the `c` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTime has a "<" operator, so you can use std::sort()

```
void SortTime(CTime vals[], size_t nVals)
{
    std::sort(vals, vals+nVals);
}
```

If you have an object containing CTimes, you can create your own "<" operator.

```
struct MyStuff
{
    std::string sName;
    int         nNumber;
    CTime       time;
};

bool operator < (const MyStuff &lhs, const MyStuff &rhs)
{
    return lhs.time < rhs.time;
}

void SortStuff(MyStuff vals[], size_t nVals)
{
    std::sort(vals, vals+nVals);
}
```

or better

```
void SortStuff(std::vector<MyStuff> vals)
{
    std::sort(vals.begin(), vals.end());
}
```

Comment: If i am having time_t as datatype then how can i sort the date?

Comment: @karthik - exactly the same.  Any data type for which the "<" operator works can work with std::sort.  And if it doesn't have a "<" operator you can make one.